# Can I Check if a Controller is Being Called from an AMP page in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm starting to implement AMP pages in my Rails 5.2 app. On desktop, I'm using the Will Paginate gem.

However, with AMP I'm using the framework's infinite scroll JS, and I don't want to paginate the results.

So in the controller action, I want to determine if the user is viewing an AMP page (the URL ends with `.amp`) to determine what I have for this line (include paginate or exclude):

`@products = @products.order('price DESC, RANDOM()').paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 24)`

How do I do this?

Comment: I think you ant to use the `request ` object.  You can read about it here and determine how to grab that `.amp` bit.  This should be able to help you get that https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-fullpath

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution is just test `request.format`. So you could write

```
if request.format == :amp 
  # do not paginate
else
  # all other formats we paginate
end
```

But inside a controller, we can also use an explicit `respond_to` block:

```
def index
  respond_to do |format|
    format.amp do 
      @products = @products.order('price DESC, RANDOM()')
    end 
    format.html do 
      @products = @products.order('price DESC, RANDOM()').paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 24)
    end 
  end
end
```

This will explicitly specify all the formats the controller method accepts and responds to.

As you probably already do, but you will have to provide a view for `index.amp` and a `index.html`.

> To be clear: this will also block all non-specified formats! E.g. retrieving a `index.json` will get a 405 Not allowed.